# Foundation 5 - How can I get Eight column grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-5

How can I implement an Eight column grid in foundation 5?

I currently have the following

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-1 columns">Today</div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">Tomorrow</div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">Wednesday</div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">Thursday</div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">Friday</div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">Saturday</div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">Sunday</div>
        <div class="large-1 columns">Monday</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Container width = 1200px

Comment: Have a look at Zurb Foundation's [custom builder](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation). You could specify the number of columns an a bunch of other settings.

Comment: what if i also needed to use the 12 grid on another page?

Comment: Then you could get the Sass version of Zurb Foundation, and make your custom grid system — Using custom class names. Have a look at: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html#customize-with-sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the comments pointed out, if you want to have a custom number of columns you'll need to use Sass.

You can follow Zurb's tutorial to get Sass and Foundation working: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

I would highly recommend using Foundation with Sass as it makes customization much easier. If you're not familiar with Sass, it will be a learning curve but should be definitely worth it! http://sass-lang.com/guide

Once you have Sass working follow the example code found here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html to get your custom column numbers working.

```
.custom-row-class {
  @include grid-row();
  .custom-column-class {
    @include grid-column(8);
  }
}
```